# If $a > 0$, $b > 0$ and $b^{3} - b^{2} = a^{3} - a^{2}$, where $a\neq b$, then prove that $a + b < 4/3$.

Tags: inequality

If $a > 0$, $b > 0$ and $b^{3} - b^{2} = a^{3} - a^{2}$, where $a\neq b$, then prove that $a + b < 4/3$.

Now what I thought is to manipulate given result somehow to get something in the form of $a + b$:
\begin{align*}
b^{3} - b^{2} = a^{3} - a^{2} & \Longleftrightarrow b^{3} - a^{3} = b^{2} - a^{2}\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (b-a)(a^{2} + ab + b^{2}) = (b+a)(b-a)\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow a^{2} + ab + b^{2} = b + a
\end{align*}

but what next?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Here's [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). Follow these guidelines to get help in this forum. For example, choose a better tittle and use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to type the math in your questions.

Comment: Please do not delete and repost the [same question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4487188/explain-your-thought-process-and-insights-on-this-question). Hint: write it as $\,(a+b)^2 - (a+b) = ab \le \dots\,$.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have:
\begin{align}
a^2+ab+b^2 = a+b &\implies 4(a+b)^2 - 4(a+b) = 4ab < (a+b)^2\\
&\implies 3(a+b)^2 - 4(a+b) < 0\\
&\implies (a+b)(3(a+b)-4) < 0\\
&\implies 3(a+b) - 4 < 0\\
&\implies (a+b) < \dfrac{4}{3}.
\end{align}

Comment: Great, but I wanted to ask that how did you come up with this solution?

Comment: First use $4ab < (a+b)^2$ to get an intequality  in terms of $a+b$ and simply solve for $a+b$

Answer (score 3):

Refer to 'Inequality of arithmetic and geometric means' in wiki
$\frac{{a + b}}{2} \geqslant \sqrt {ab}  \Rightarrow \frac{{{{(a + b)}^2}}}{4} \geqslant ab$

Next,

$\begin{gathered}
  {a^2} + ab + {b^2} = a + b \hfill \\
  {(a + b)^2} = a + b + ab < a + b + \frac{{{{(a + b)}^2}}}{4} \hfill \\
  \frac{{3{{(a + b)}^2}}}{4} < a + b \hfill \\
  a + b < \frac{4}{3} \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} $

Comment: Great, but I wanted to ask that how did you come up with this solution?

Answer (score 1):

Rearrange $a^3-a^2=b^3-b^2$ to get
$$
b^3-a^3=b^2-a^2.
$$
Since $a\neq b$ we can factor out $(b-a)$ from both sides to get
$$
a^2+ab+b^2=a+b
$$
which is equivalent to
$$
(a+b)^2-ab=a+b
$$
Let $Q\equiv a+b$ then by the AM-GM inequality $\sqrt ab\leq(a+b)/2=Q/2$, and since $a\neq b$ the inequality is strict ($\sqrt ab < (a+b)/2$). Squaring this gives $ab<Q^2/4$.
We now have
$$
Q^2-Q<Q^2/4
$$
and since $a>0$, $b>0$ we can factor out a $Q$ and rearrange to get
$$
3/4Q<1\equiv Q<4/3.
$$